# Github commits not showing up

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I changed around my git config user.email and git config user.name because I was testing stuff out. Now, I can push to the repo, but the commits aren't showing up on my actual github account.

From the image below, you can see that the commits look like they're from two accounts, but I am using the same username and password to make both of those commits. I think the problem is with user.email and user.name, but I am not sure.

The commits are definitely being pushed as the changes are shown on the website.

[Snippet of commit history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wdP5.png)

Comment: Can you double check that your email matches the one used on github?

Comment: It's not based on my git log, the one that matches git hub is ..@gmail.com and the one that the commit is under is ...@github.com. How do I change this? Changing it by `git config --global user.email youremail@email.com` does not fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you do `git log`, are the username and email exactly the same as your github?

If not, change them again with the following:

```
git config --global user.name yourusername
git config --global user.email youremail@email.com
```

Comment: My gitlog shows the commits that are showing on my profile are from the email address associated with the github. However, even when I changed the username and email using the commands you specified to that email address, and pushed again, the git log shows the last commit was from jasonbak@github.com, which isn't the email associated with my github.